# Debian Server Daemon: File sync

Tags: debian, synchronization

I'm looking for a way to (auto) sync files on some pcs over the internet and save/backup them on my server.
Just like Dropbox and other services like that.
I found iFolder (by Novell), but it's not made for debian (i think it would still compile). I don't know if it's made for an webserver or just home server.
Another way would be FTP, I don't know clients (i use ubuntu and windows on my pcs), which autoupload new/edited files.
There is also svn/csv, but they are quite slow (afaik), and I don't know if there are suited for this.

Someone got an idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inotify with rsync will do exactly what you have asked for.

Look at this link for [inotify-tools](http://wiki.github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/).

Example 1 show you in **11 lines of bash script** how to achieve what you have asked for: 
a monitored directory that automatically rsyncs changes to a remote server for backup.

I am fairly sure the iFolder was based on inotify, I thought iFolder died out a while ago.

I did knock up my own application ages ago based on bazaar version control system but it is slow and complicated when compared to inotify.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at chironfs : it can synchronize in real time two filesystems. It's based on fuse. It's really easy to compile and works well between my two Linux boxes.